# Replacing values in a vector with values from another vector in R

Tags: r, csv, vector

I am having trouble replacing values in a vector with values from another vector.  The basic program logic is this:

1. Establish a keyword list (code omitted for this).
2. Establish a maximum occurrence vector.  This is a vector which contains the keywords and the maximum occurrence when the keywords are compared with CSV files.

For example, my keyword list looks like this

ABILITY

DEVELOPS

ENVIRONMENTAL
...

my maximum occurrence vector is created from the keyword list and is initialized like this

ABILITY 0

DEVELOPS 0

ENVIRONMENTAL 0

and now I am comparing the maximum occurrence vector with CSV files like this

### file 1

ABILITY  3

DEVELOPS  5

ENVIRONMENTAL  4

### file 2

ABILITY  5

DEVELOPS  7

ENVIRONMENTAL  1

So basically I would like to populate the maximum occurrence vector with the maximum from file 1 and 2.  For example, in the maximum occurrence vector, the maximum occurrence for ENVIRONMENTAL should be changed to 4 (the maximum occurrence after scanning file 1 and file 2).  Here's my code:

```
# Find the largest frequency of the given keywords by searching the keyword sets

# Start by defining and initializing the max occurence vector

keywordslength=length(keywords)
keywordmax=data.frame(keywords)
keywordmax$Max=0

# Start by reading the keyword set and keeping the frequency of the keyword
ksearch1=read.csv("set1.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
ksearch1$V1=toupper(ksearch1$V1)

# Now scan ksearch1 for the word in question
    for (i in 1:keywordslength)
{
    # Establish the keyword
    testkey=keywords[i]
    testmax=0

    # Scan ksearch1     
    for (j in 1:length(ksearch1$V1))
    {
        if (ksearch1[j,1]==testkey)
        {
            testmax=ksearch1[j,2]

        }

        if (subset(keywordmax, keywords==testkey, select=c(Max))>=testmax)
        {
            keywordmax[which(keywords==testkey),2]=testmax
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong.  The line reading "if (subset(keywordmax, keywords==testkey, select=c(Max))>=testmax)" should have the >= as a <= instead.

I'm sure this could all be done in like three lines with some sapply but I am fairly new to the language and am use to for loops.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

Create the list of keywords and the two files

```
keywords <- as.data.frame(c("Ability","Develops","Environmental"))
max_occur <- data.frame(keywords,c(0,0,0))
file1 <- data.frame(keywords,c(3,5,4))
file2 <- data.frame(keywords,c(5,7,1))
```

Rename the columns appropriately

```
colnames(file1) <- c("V1","V2")
colnames(file2) <- c("V1","V2")
colnames(keywords) <- c("V1")
colnames(max_occur) <- c("V1","V2")
```

Sort the data frames according to the keywords

```
keywords <- as.data.frame(keywords[sort(keywords$V1,decreasing = FALSE),])
max_occur <- as.data.frame(max_occur[sort(max_occur$V1,decreasing = FALSE),])
file1 <- file1[sort(file1$V1,decreasing=FALSE),]
file2 <- file2[sort(file2$V1,decreasing=FALSE),]
```

Rename them since they are converted to factors

```
colnames(keywords) <- c("V1")
colnames(max_occur) <- c("V1","V2")
```

Find the largest value and store in `max_occur`

```
for(i in 1:length(keywords$V1)){
  max_occur$V2[i] <- max(max_occur$V2[i],file1$V2[i],file2$V2[i])  
}
```

Let me know if all keywords are not present in each file. I'll change the code a bit. From what you've posted. They all appear in each file.